# Why aren't toList and friends deprecated?

Tags: scala

Prior to version 2.10 of Scala sequence types had methods like `toList` and `toArray` for converting from one type to another.  As of Scala 2.10 we have `to[_]`, e.g. `to[List]`, which appears to subsume `toList` and friends and also give us the ability to convert to new types like `Vector` and presumably even to our own collection types.  And of course it gives you the ability to convert to a type which you know only as a type parameter, e.g. `to[A]` -- nice!

But why weren't the old methods deprecated?  Are they faster?  Are there cases where `toList` works but `to[List]` does not?  Should we prefer one over the other where both work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`toList` is implemented in `TraversableOnce` as `to[List]`, so there won't be any noticeable performance difference.

However, `toArray` is (very slightly) more efficient than `to[Array]` as the former allocates an array of the right size while the latter first creates an array and then sets the size hint (as it does for every target collection type). This should not make a difference in a real application unless you are converting data to arrays in a tight loop.

The old methods could easily be deprecated, and I bet they will in the future, but people are so used to them that deprecating them right away would probably make some people angry.

Comment: `toXXX` can easily be overwritten, like it is the case for [`toList`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L196), not only for `toArray`.

Comment: Indeed, it is easier than overwrite and special case `to`.

Comment: Ummm, Samuel, you look awfully young -- does your mother know you are looking at the Scala collections source code?

Comment: @AmigoNico Shhh, don't tell her or she might stop feeding me!

Answer (score 2):

On issue seems to be that you cannot use to[] in postfix notation:

```
scala> Array(1,2) toList
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> Array(1,2) to[List]
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but '[' found.
       Array(1,2) to[List]

scala> Array(1,2).to[List]
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

Comment: `xs toList` produces a warning, don't hide that one.

Comment: @sschaef: Not if you do an `import scala.language.postfixOps`